# ユーザー登録せずに投稿したのですが、その時のアカウントにアクセスできません

Tags: サポート, よくある質問の案

ユーザー登録を行わずゲストとして投稿したのですが、しばらくしてからサイトを見ると、自分の投稿の編集やコメントができなくなっていました。投稿時のアカウントが使えなくなっていると思うのですが、どうすればいいですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

基本的には、ユーザー登録（パスワードの設定）をしていただくことになります。

投稿時に使ったメールアドレスを[アカウント復元フォーム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/account-recovery)に入力すると、パスワードを設定するためのメールが届きます。最初に投稿したときに届くメールにもパスワード設定リンクが載っているので、それを使うこともできます。

> 質問時のアカウントにアクセスできないからといって、**コメントや追加情報を回答として投稿するのは避けてください** 。そのような回答はほかのユーザーやモデレーターによるレビューにより削除されることがあります。
>
> 質問の編集はログインしていない状態でも編集提案という形で行えますが、質問者なのかどうかわからない等の理由で提案が却下されるかもしれません。

なお、この手順に沿ってユーザー登録を行っても別のアカウントが作成されてしまうことがあります。その場合は次の説明に沿ってマージを依頼してください。

#### 気づかずに別のアカウントを作ってしまった

アカウントをひとつにまとめる（マージ）ことができます。どちらかのアカウントでログインした状態で、 [お問い合わせフォーム](/contact) からご連絡ください。

#### 最初に使ったメールアドレスを忘れてしまった

心当たりのあるメールアドレスがいくつかあれば、順番にアカウント復元フォームで試してみてください。そのメールアドレスで使われているアカウントの有無がメールで届きます。

全く見当もつかない場合、あるいは最初にメールアドレスを間違えたかもしれない場合は、改めて新規アカウントを作成し、[お問い合わせフォーム](/contact) からマージを依頼してください。